# C++ - Linked List Insertion Sort (String elements)

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've a homework task, where I've to sort linked list elements (strings) after first character in a string.
Example:

**From:** Pineapple->Apple->Ash->Abc->Pearl->Bonfire->Ball

**To:**  **A**pple->**A**sh->**A**bc->**B**onfire->**B**all->**P**ineapple->**P**earl (Only first char)

I made a function:

```
void insertionSort ()
{
    first = current;
    Node* insertionPointer = first;
    current = current -> next;
    for (start(); !end(); next()){ // Running through all list nodes
        while (current != NULL) {
            insertionPointer = first;
            while(insertionPointer->next != current) {
                if (insertionPointer->data.at(0) > current-> data.at(0)){   // Trying to sort strings alphabetically
                                                                            // (after only first char)
                    string temp = current->data;
                    current->data = insertionPointer->data;
                    insertionPointer->data = temp;
                }
                else {
                    insertionPointer = insertionPointer->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a segmentation fault - I guess that means I'm trying to get some information, that I can not access? Also, I'm not sure if:

```
if (insertionPointer->data.at(0) > current-> data.at(0))
```

Will compare strings first char? I'm just trying to experiment here. :(
Just to make sure, I'll post below also my whole code, so you can see how I structured lists and other functions. I'm new to this stuff - any information will be helpful.

Full program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
class Node
 {
public:
string data;
Node *next;
Node (string city) { data = city; next = NULL; };
};
class List
{
protected:
    Node *first, *last;
public:
    Node *current;
public:
    List () { first = last = current = NULL; };

 void add_element (string city);
 void delete_element ();
 ~List();

 bool is_empty () { return (first == NULL); };
 void start () { current = first; };
 bool end () { return (current == NULL); };
 void next(){if (!end())current = current -> next;};
 void print();

void insertionSort ()
{
first = current;
Node* insertionPointer = first;
current = current -> next;
for (start(); !end(); next()){ // Running through all list nodes
while (current != NULL) {
    insertionPointer = first;
    while(insertionPointer->next != current)  {
                        if (insertionPointer->data.at(0) >  current->data.at(0)){   // Trying to sort strings alphabetically
                                                                                    // (after only first char)
                        string temp = current->data;
                        current->data = insertionPointer->data;
                        insertionPointer->data = temp;
                        }else{
                        insertionPointer = insertionPointer->next;
                        }
    }
}
    }
}


};


int main()
{
string s;
List l;

l.add_element("Pineapple");
l.add_element("Apple");
l.add_element("Ash");
l.add_element("Abc");
l.add_element("Pearl");
l.add_element("Bonfire");
l.add_element("Ball");


l.print();
cout << endl;
l.insertionSort();
l.print();



return 0;
}

void List::add_element (string city)
{
 Node *p = new Node (city);
 if (first == NULL) first = last = p;
 else last = last -> next = p;
 current = p;
};

void List::delete_element ()
 {
 Node *p = first;
 if(!is_empty())
 { if (current == first) current = first-> next;
 first = first -> next;
 delete p;
 if(is_empty())last = NULL;
 }
 };
void List::print()
{
for (start(); !end(); next())
{
cout << current->data << endl;
}
cout << endl;
};
List::~List()
{
while (!is_empty())
 {
delete_element();
};
cout << "All memory of nodes deleted!"<< endl;
};
```

Comment: Please do not get input from an unknown file (to us).  Just call the requisite list functions with known, hard-coded values.  That is how you're supposed to test, and especially if others want to duplicate the issue.  If `add_element("abc"); add_element("123"); add_element("Joe"); add_element("Bob"); insertionSort();` does not work, reading from a file isn't going to work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I took your advice and changed my main function in code. I still can't solve: 1. Segmentation fault 2. " if (insertionPointer->data.at(0) >  current->data.at(0)){  " Will this statement sort after only first char of strings?

Comment: your logic is all wrong. your `add:element` should insert sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is most likely crashing here:

```
while(insertionPointer->next != current)  {
```

because `insertionPointer` has become null when you executed

```
insertionPointer = insertionPointer->next;
```

change the loop condition to

```
while(insertionPointer && insertionPointer->next != current)  {
```

Comment: Still gives me segmentation fault.

Comment: your code is completely changed and it doesn't crash see [your code live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9573530a60cc760a). it doesn't sort either..